# Android C++/Gradle/NDK: what flags should I pass to cppFlags, cFlags or arguments?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I see here a typical example of Gradle file for a NDK project.

Nevertheless, I wonder what are the rules to know where to put the different flags:

```
    // Passes optional arguments to CMake.
       arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang"
    
    // Sets a flag to enable format macro constants for the C compiler.
       cFlags "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS"
    
   // Sets optional flags for the C++ compiler.
      cppFlags "-fexceptions", "-frtti"
```

For example, why "-fexceptions", "-frtti" are in 'cppFlags' and not in 'arguments' ? What are the rules to decide and the influence on compilation/app runtime/performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet you linked to clearly indicates the audience for each setting:

1. When Gradle needs to build the native component of your application, it calls CMake for every ABI in scope. Thus, `arguments` are for the CMake invocation.
2. CMake itself does not actually build your native component, it just sets up a set of files for your build system. Typically this tool is Ninja or Make.
3. The `cFlags` and `cppFlags` are embedded in the build rules for the respective files. Files with a `.c` extension are built with the C compiler so they get the `cFlags`, and likewise `cppFlags` for `.cpp` or `.cc`. The exact mechanism how these flags get to the respective compilers is not very interesting so I will skip that.

To answer your last question: you need to inspect your CMakeLists.txt to see which properties it looks for and interprets. There is also a whole slew of [CMake built-in variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) that can be set from the commandline.

You can consult the [Clang user's guide](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#command-line-options) and the [Clang commandline reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html). Often you can figure out from the description whether it is a C or a C++ flag.